# what does findWhere() function do in laravel query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

in function findWhere is used what does findWhere() do..
in laravel where means a condition
this is also condition but i don't know what does it mean what exactly findWhere do here

thanks in advance

```
public function getInfluencerCampaign($request)
   {
       return $this->with(["invite" => function($query) use ($request){
           $query->with(['campaign' => function($campaignQuery) use($request) {
               $campaignQuery->select(['id', 'name', 'slug','objective_id'])
                   ->with(['payment'  => function($query){
                       $query->with(['paymentType' => function($paymentQuery){
                           $paymentQuery->select(['id', 'name']);
                       }])->select(['payment_type_id', 'campaign_id']);
                   },
                   'objective' => function($objectiveQuery){
                       $objectiveQuery->select(['id', 'name', 'slug']);
                   },
                   'statistics' => function($statisticQuery) use ($request){
                       $statisticQuery->select(['user_id','campaign_id','placement_id','work_rate','rating', 'eng_rate', 'comment_count', 'like_count', 'follower_count'])
                           ->where('user_id',$request->input('user_id'));
                   }
                   ]);
           }]);
       }])
       ->findWhere([
           'assign_to_id' => $request->input('user_id'),
       ])->groupBy('campaign_invite_id');
   }
```

Comment: Find by result by multiple fields "assign_to_id" is condition to find the result

Comment: upvote if you understand